# Rubocop - ArgumentAlignment does not appear to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

**Posting this question and deleted my original because it was not properly describing the issue**

I've been working on getting things aligned properly in my code.  I am looking to try and enforce this:

```
method(
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
)
```

and not

```
method( key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
)
```

also not

```
method(
  key1: 'value1',
         key2: 'value2'
)
```

This is where things are falling down.

I currently have:

```
Layout/FirstMethodArgumentLineBreak
Layout/FirstArgumentIndentation
```

Those get me 99% of the way.  However, the only way it appears to get the last piece working is

```
Layout/ArgumentAlignment
```

I've tried both `EnforcedStyle: with_first_argument` as well as `EnforcedStyle: with_fixed_indentation` (both of which in this case should be the same).  However, nothing ever gets flagged when they are not aligned.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue...we are currently using ruby-2.4.x, which only allows up to rubocop 1.12.1.  We are currently working on upgrading to 2.6.8.

I found that Layout/AttributeAlignment is not working properly in 1.12.1, however it is working in the current version 1.45.1.

So this is a notice to anyone still using the older version that this cop is not currently working properly.